# Sharpness of images on specular vs diffuse surfaces

Tags: optics, microscopy

I'm observing a confusing phenomenon where I'm projecting an image [episcopically](https://www.microscopyu.com/techniques/stereomicroscopy/reflected-episcopic-light-illumination) through an objective into a substrate while observing it through a camera (think [structured illumination](https://youtu.be/i73HhpLJrqs?t=545) for a microscope). When I project the image onto a specular surface (polished aluminum for instance) both the features of the substrate and the image appear sharp through the camera. However, when I project onto a diffuse surface such as paper the projected image appears blurry through the camera.

To give some extra details, the objective is a reversed camera lens and the optical system has an infinity space where a plate beam splitter lives. The camera is focused to infinity and a glass plate with some patterns on it is placed at the focal point of a tube lens. On a specular surface both the features on the surface (e.g. dust) and the features of the projected image can be simultaneously brought into focus and appear sharp on the camera. But when I focus on something non reflective, the projected image features can't be brought into focus.

I don't think it's a depth of field issue, as for example I can resolve printed text on paper or diffuse plastic just fine. So fine height variations don't appear to be the culprit. Even projecting onto parchment paper gives poor result, and this material is very smooth.

My thoughts are that the diffuse surface is acting like a spatial filter (confocal system) causing poor image quality due to refraction.

Could there be an obvious explanation for what I'm observing?

[image: optical set up]